# How to answer a command from the Terminal in Java

Tags: java, terminal, linux-mint

I want to execute a command from Java but this command wants me to give it a username.

Like this example:

> $ my command
>
> [command] Username:_

So how can I give the command my username in Java?

Currently my code is like this:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    br.close();
    p.waitFor();
    p.destroy();
```

Comment: Doesn't it provide a parameter to provide the username right away?

Comment: Have you considered using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another thread and pump user input through `process#getOutputStream()`. See the following example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ProcessWithInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat");
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        os.write("Hello World".getBytes());
        os.close();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        br.close();
        p.waitFor();
        p.destroy();
    }
}
```

Ofcourse, you need to do proper error/exception handling etc.

Other option is to use `ProcessBuilder` which allows you to provide input through a File.

Comment: Sorry but, can you explain me how I can specify the username?

Comment: Look at the edited code. In general, whetever you write to `p.getOutputStream()` will be written to the process's input stream. Note that you may have to either flush or close the output stream for the process to get the input.